# WCF : How to handle a connection loss with the client?

Tags: c#, wcf, http

I am currently developing an IoT that performs HTTP requests to my WCF web server via the GPRS service (GSM Network).

The thing is : I very often (due to the bad GPRS RSSI on my connected object) lose the connection to the GPRS service. The problem is that sometimes, when I perform an HTTP GET on my server, it generates a timeout on the object's side (HTTP code 408), while the server actually received the request : it means that I had connection when I queried the server, but I lost it right after.
However, the server isn't aware of the fact that my object lost the connection, so it will do what it was told to do anyway (delete stuff in the database etc.).
I need **very precise** synchronization between the object and the server, and I don't want the server to perform database changes if my object loses the connection and doesn't receive the server's response. Which is why I would like to know it this is possible, with WCF, to know if at the end of the API function Call, the server successfully responded to the query or not (have some sort of ACK to be sure that the HTTP communication fully worked on both sides).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using session state in your service? You can accomplish accurate connection state using a heartbeat keep alive call.

Comment: I do not handle the session state at all for now. Maybe I could do an heartbeat, but you have to keep in mind that this is a connected object using GPRS, so I want to :
- use the less data as possible
- close the Http Session (shut down GPRS services) ASAP